# YUM says "no package XXX" when the package should exist

Tags: yum

I reinstalled Centos 7 twice over the past couple of days from the same live usb.

The first time, I installed a bunch of packages I needed in the following (typical) manner `sudo yum install XXX` where `XXX` was a package, such as `ntfs-3g`, `qemu`, or `geany`. This time around, I'm getting `No package XXX available.`

As I said, I used the same live usb on the same machine. I'm fairly certain that I ran `sudo yum update` both times (I definitely did this install as I have multiple kernel versions installed).

Here is some info that might be useful:

Centos version

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

Enabled Repos

```
$ yum repolist enabled
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.sonn.com
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirror.hmc.edu
repo id                             repo name                             status
base/7/x86_64                       CentOS-7 - Base                       9,007
extras/7/x86_64                     CentOS-7 - Extras                       264
updates/7/x86_64                    CentOS-7 - Updates                    1,213
repolist: 10,484
```

Same thing except verbose

```
$ yum repolist enabled -v
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "langpacks" plugin
Adding en_US to language list
Config time: 0.008
Yum version: 3.4.3
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.sonn.com
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirror.hmc.edu
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.004
Repo-id      : base/7/x86_64
Repo-name    : CentOS-7 - Base
Repo-revision: 1449700451
Repo-updated : Wed Dec  9 14:35:45 2015
Repo-pkgs    : 9,007
Repo-size    : 6.5 G
Repo-mirrors : http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock
Repo-baseurl : http://centos.sonn.com/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/ (9 more)
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Sun Apr  3 13:07:31 2016)
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

Repo-id      : extras/7/x86_64
Repo-name    : CentOS-7 - Extras
Repo-revision: 1459508613
Repo-updated : Fri Apr  1 04:03:51 2016
Repo-pkgs    : 264
Repo-size    : 704 M
Repo-mirrors : http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=extras&infra=stock
Repo-baseurl : http://mirror.tocici.com/centos/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/ (9 more)
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Sun Apr  3 13:07:31 2016)
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

Repo-id      : updates/7/x86_64
Repo-name    : CentOS-7 - Updates
Repo-revision: 1459456033
Repo-updated : Thu Mar 31 13:30:30 2016
Repo-pkgs    : 1,213
Repo-size    : 3.3 G
Repo-mirrors : http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=updates&infra=stock
Repo-baseurl : http://mirror.hmc.edu/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/ (9 more)
Repo-expire  : 21,600 second(s) (last: Sun Apr  3 13:07:31 2016)
Repo-filename: /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

repolist: 10,484
```

All repos

```
$ yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.sonn.com
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirror.hmc.edu
repo id                         repo name                         status
C7.0.1406-base/x86_64           CentOS-7.0.1406 - Base            disabled
C7.0.1406-centosplus/x86_64     CentOS-7.0.1406 - CentOSPlus      disabled
C7.0.1406-extras/x86_64         CentOS-7.0.1406 - Extras          disabled
C7.0.1406-fasttrack/x86_64      CentOS-7.0.1406 - CentOSPlus      disabled
C7.0.1406-updates/x86_64        CentOS-7.0.1406 - Updates         disabled
C7.1.1503-base/x86_64           CentOS-7.1.1503 - Base            disabled
C7.1.1503-centosplus/x86_64     CentOS-7.1.1503 - CentOSPlus      disabled
C7.1.1503-extras/x86_64         CentOS-7.1.1503 - Extras          disabled
C7.1.1503-fasttrack/x86_64      CentOS-7.1.1503 - CentOSPlus      disabled
C7.1.1503-updates/x86_64        CentOS-7.1.1503 - Updates         disabled
base/7/x86_64                   CentOS-7 - Base                   enabled: 9,007
base-debuginfo/x86_64           CentOS-7 - Debuginfo              disabled
base-source/7                   CentOS-7 - Base Sources           disabled
c7-media                        CentOS-7 - Media                  disabled
centosplus/7/x86_64             CentOS-7 - Plus                   disabled
centosplus-source/7             CentOS-7 - Plus Sources           disabled
cr/7/x86_64                     CentOS-7 - cr                     disabled
extras/7/x86_64                 CentOS-7 - Extras                 enabled:   264
extras-source/7                 CentOS-7 - Extras Sources         disabled
fasttrack/7/x86_64              CentOS-7 - fasttrack              disabled
updates/7/x86_64                CentOS-7 - Updates                enabled: 1,213
updates-source/7                CentOS-7 - Updates Sources        disabled
repolist: 10,484
```

Searching for geany

```
yum search geany
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.sonn.com
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirror.hmc.edu
Warning: No matches found for: geany
No matches found
```

Searching for qemu

```
$ yum search qemu
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.sonn.com
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirror.hmc.edu
============================== N/S matched: qemu ===============================
centos-release-qemu-ev.noarch : QEMU Enterprise Virtualization packages from the
                              : CentOS Virtualization SIG repository
ipxe-roms-qemu.noarch : Network boot loader roms supported by QEMU, .rom format
libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu.x86_64 : Qemu driver plugin for the libvirtd daemon
qemu-guest-agent.x86_64 : QEMU guest agent
qemu-img.x86_64 : QEMU command line tool for manipulating disk images
qemu-kvm.x86_64 : QEMU is a FAST! processor emulator
qemu-kvm-common.x86_64 : QEMU common files needed by all QEMU targets
libvirt-lock-sanlock.x86_64 : Sanlock lock manager plugin for QEMU driver
qemu-kvm-tools.x86_64 : KVM debugging and diagnostics tools

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

There are some hits with that one, but I recall `yum install qemu` would work and install a whole bunch of qemu packages.

Trying to install `qemu`

```
$ sudo yum install qemu
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.sonn.com
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: centos.eecs.wsu.edu
No package qemu available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

And ironically I can't resolve dependencies for my password manager because of all this, so I can't log in to my SE account.

Is fixing this as simple as add/enabling a repo?

Comment: Use `yum list available` to see what packages exist, in case you have the package name close but not exact.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I just did an looked through it without finding anything. I am pretty positive that the commands as listed in the question worked in the past. I have used them on several machines.

Comment: It looks to me like "yum install" wants the precise package name, while "yum search" does substring matches. Does "yum install qemu-kvm" (for example) work?

Comment: In either case, it seems to be in EPEL, which I don't see in your log.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, it does. I'm not having trouble installing anything that yum knows about. Rather, I think that yum doesn't know about things that it should.

Comment: @ThomasDickey EPEL isn't "Extras"? Well I suppose that would explain everything. I'll go add it.

Comment: EPEL is "Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux", which should show in the `yum repolist` in a recognizable form.

Comment: geany and ntfs-3g are also only available via epel or repoforge, see http://pkgs.org/search/geany and http://pkgs.org/search/ntfs-3g

Answer (score 1):

There is a `qemu` package in EPEL ([Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/install-epel-and-additional-repositories-on-centos-and-red-hat/)).  When listing repositories, that would not show as "Extras" for CentOS.

The RPM finder is useful for seeing that it is in EPEL:

- [RPM resource qemu](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=qemu&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=) (mentions EPEL)
- [RPM resource qemu-system-x86](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=qemu-system-x86&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=) (again mentions EPEL)